# BindingResult issue with  @spring.formTextarea

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

Hello I'm using Spring MVC with Freemarker.
The case I face now that  the controller returns a list of Student.
And from within the Freemarker,I loop over this list and I pass the age,property inside the student,to

```
spring.formTextarea
```

I get the  exception mentioned below.

My Freemarker:

```
[#list studentResults as studentInstance]
                    <td>${studentInstance.name}</td>
                    <td>[@spring.formTextarea path="{studentInstance}.age" attributes="class=\"input-large\" placeholder=\"Enter the name you need to search for \" "/]</td>
[/#list]
```

> Exception:
>
> > Mar 31, 2012 5:13:42 AM freemarker.log.JDK14LoggerFactory$JDK14Logger
> >     error SEVERE:
> >
> > Method public org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String)
> >     throws java.lang.IllegalStateException threw an exception when invoked
> >     on org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@11fb8c6 with
> >
> > ### arguments of types [java.lang.String,] The problematic instruction:
>
> ==> assignment: status=springMacroRequestContext.getBindStatus(path) [on line 120, column 9 in spring.ftl]  in user-directive bind [on line
>   204, column 5 in spring.ftl]  in user-directive spring.formTextarea
>
> ### [on line 39, column 25 in find.ftl]
>
> Java backtrace for programmers:
>   ---------- freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.IllegalStateException threw an exception when invoked
>   on org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@11fb8c6 with
>   arguments of types [java.lang.String,]    at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:134)
>     at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
>     at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
>     at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90)    at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:168)    at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:602)   at
>   freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)  at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:168)    at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:602)   at
>   freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)  at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:179)
>     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:416)  at
>   freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)  at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189)     at
>   freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name '12222' available as request attribute    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:722)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:840)
>     at
>   freemarker.ext.beans.OverloadedMethodModel.exec(OverloadedMethodModel.java:104)
>     ... 60 more

Answer (score 0):

i believe path can be recognized for the commandName objects declared at the spring:form level, for example if you want to bind the age of person object then you should have done like

```
<form:form action="/submit" commandName="person">
  <form:textArea path="age"/>
</form>
```

by doing this it will automactically maps to the modelAttribute "person" you are bringing from the controller. In your case i dont think so it will automatically bind the age to the text area. This is just a guess, I am not sure how you are bringing the whole list of studentResults from the controller and also how you have bind the form backing bean between the controller and the view.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same `textarea` issue, where I need to populate the `modelAttribute` value, as well capture the value when submitting the rendered form. 
  I tried with `<spring:bind>` approach, but it didn't work- I keep on getting a binding status error.

1. As an alternative I added a JavaScript to populate the value on pageload.

   ```
     function populateTextArea(){
       document.getElementById('description').value =
        document.getElementById('dummyDescription').value;
       }
       </script>
       </head>
       <body  onload="populateTextArea(); ">
   ```
2. However for capturing the value, I used path element. The same approach spring form tag uses:

   ```
   <sform:textarea path="description" id="description" value="${objectDTO.description}"/>
   <input type="hidden" id="dummyDescription" value="${objectDTO.description}"/>
   ```

This might not be a good approach, but a temporary solution for any spring binding error.